# AWS Amplify for Android - Cannot resolve symbol 'AmplifyModelProvider'

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

Good day all,

I am implementing [AWS Amplify DataStore for android](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started?platform=android) following the docs, and basically i get this error when i try to initialize the data store plugin on amplify according to [this part of the doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started?platform=android#initialization):

**Cannot resolve symbol 'AmplifyModelProvider'**

You can find code from my gradle files and my application class below.

I am not an android expert, but i believe this is because of a missing dependency or i am doing something wrong during initialization or assignation of the ModelProvider. But i cant find any information on internet about this issue or any possible solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new android project
2. Install Amplify CLI, using npm, `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`
3. Configure amplify, `amplify configure`
4. On new android project root folder, run amplify init, `amplify init`
5. On new android project root folder, run amplify add auth, `amplify add auth`, adding authentication
6. Create android application class
7. Add android application class to AndroidManifest.xml
8. Try to add data store plugin to amplify on onCreate method of the application class

I already try the following solutions:

1. Clean project
2. Rebuild project
3. Run Make Project
4. Close and open again Android Studio

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bakeano.htejobs">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.bakeano.htejobs;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.Callback;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.UserStateDetails;
import com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AWSApiPlugin;
import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify;
import com.amplifyframework.core.model.ModelProvider;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.AWSDataStorePlugin;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // AWSMobileClient initialization
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(UserStateDetails result) {
                try {
                    ModelProvider modelProvider = AmplifyModelProvider.getInstance(); // Error on this line !!!
                    Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin.forModels(modelProvider));
                    Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSApiPlugin());
                    Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("bakeanoMessage", "Amplify adding plugins Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.e("bakeanoMessage", "AWSMobileClient init Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bakeano.htejobs"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // androidx constraint layout
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'

    // aws amplify framework core
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:0.10.0'

    // AWSMobileClient
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.11'

    // aws amplify for the drop-in ui
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.16.11'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.16.11'

    // aws amplify api
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:0.10.0'

    // aws amplify data store
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:0.10.0'

}
```

Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'

        // amplify tools gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.amplifyframework:amplify-tools-gradle-plugin:0.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// applying the amplify tools plugin
apply plugin: 'com.amplifyframework.amplifytools'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution provided by [Jameson Williams](https://github.com/jamesonwilliams):

at [projects github issue platform - issue #370](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/370)

AmplifyModelProvider is an autogenerated file that is created by amplify [codegen](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started?platform=android#manual-model-generation)

`amplify codegen models`

after manual generation you need to import it:

`import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.AmplifyModelProvider;`

Thanks !!

Comment: Glad this worked! To note: in Amplify 1.0, the `AmplifyModelProvider` is found by reflection. So, you can just do `new AWSDataStorePlugin()` without specifying any explicit model provider.